# Tab Bar not visible in navigation controller

Tags: swift, xcode

I created the following Tab Bar Application in xcode.  The problem is the tab bar is not visible on the Table View that uses a navigation controller (#2 below).  I would like the tabbar to remain visible at #2 below. The Navigation Controller (#1 in picture) "Bottom Bar" is set to 'Inferred'.  The Navigation Controller (#1 in picture) has set the "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" not checked.

Note: #0, #1, #2 are marked below just for referencing them here.

[image]

I would like the tab bar to be visible at #2 below.  If you need additional information please do not downvote, just ask me and I will provide it.  Thank you.

Comment: Check if you have `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` set in your #2

Comment: Thanks Iur.   I checked #2 and there is no check on "Hide Bottom Bar on Push".

Comment: add tabbar Item in navigation controller's bottom bar(which is transculent Tabbar) with add same title and image that in#2 VC

Comment: It's not visible when you run the app or it's not visible while looking at it in the storyboard?

Comment: Andrew, It's not visible in storyboard and it's not visible when I run the app.  Sorry I did not mention that.

Comment: Are you sure you push it properly? Maybe you present it modally somehow?

Comment: I am relatively new to xcode.  I created a new tab based app, then I added the navigation controller so that I can have a save button on the top (#1 and #2 in picture).  Could that be the problem: that I should not have added a navigation controller?

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved!  Steps to solve it:

1. Deleted the navigation controller (#1 above).
2. Then selected item #0 above and chose "Editor"->"Embed in"->"Navigation Controller"
3. Recreated the segue between #0 and #2 above. (Since it was deleted when the navigation controller was deleted in step 1 above)

Works perfect now.